# how to catch jquery custom events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, try-catch

I have created a jquery custom event in my iframe which is inside my main page. I have triggered a custom event as shown in the following doc

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```

There are several examples on how this can be caught using jquery. But the main page which has the iframe embedded doesn't have jquery so I have to have plain javascript code catch this event. I didn't find any documentation online for this. Any ideas/links/pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: don't you have access to main page code and simply install jQuery? Sounds like you might be trying to acccess main page that's not even on your domain... in which case you're going to run into same domain security restrictions

Comment: as far as I know, you can't trigger an event inside the iframe using events outside iframe..

Comment: can you please post the code snippet u r using

Comment: the only reason you should be using an iframe is if the content is another domain and if so you don't have control over that.  You can't trigger events on someone else's website.  I don't know why this ? got upvoted

Comment: If you cannot have jquery in the main, why dont you write plain old javascript on both sides?

Comment: Hakan Hastekin: how do I do that? Any examples/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Add native event listener in your main page
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener